# want to count total number of rows in table

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am doing knockout binding for inserting values into the table.
If there is nuber of rows in table is 0, then I have to show an alert message.
But for that I need to count the number of rows showing data.

my view's code is as Below:

```
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered datagrid" style="width: 355px;" id="remodellingTable">
       <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody data-bind="foreach:items">
          <tr>
             <td data-bind="text:fname" id="tdfname"></td>
             <td data-bind="text:lname"></td>
             <td data-bind="text:addr"></td>
             <td data-bind="text:city"></td>
             <td data-bind="text:state"></td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="nexttarget"> Next <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

and my jquery code for this checking is as below:

```
$('#nexttarget').live('click', function () 
{
     var rowcount = ('#remodellingTable > tbody > tr').length;
    if (rowcount > 0) 
    {
       $('#authorize').hide();
       $('#target').hide();
       $('#sideone').show();
    }
    else 
    {
       alert("There are no targets selected");
    }

}
```

Comment: So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Did you mean to do `$('#remodelling` ...  You're missing the `$`

Comment: I think `var rowcount = $('#remodellingTable > tbody > tr:has([data-bind])').length;` should work

Comment: Nice catch @ExplosionPills I missed that

Comment: it shows value of rowcount as '30'

Comment: @rahul That's the length of the string...

Comment: @nbrooks I inserted that '$' in my code 
now its working & thanks

Comment: No problem, minor typo. Happens to all of us. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to invoke jQuery, using `$`:

```
var rowcount = $('#remodellingTable > tbody > tr').length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ENQrX/

If you don't invoke jQuery, you're simply evaluating the length of the string `'#remodellingTable > tbody > tr'`, which is obviously irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
var rowcount = $('#remodellingTable > tbody > tr').length;
```

instead of  `var rowcount = ('#remodellingTable > tbody > tr').length;`